# git pull and fast forward merging

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, git-pull, pull

My question is simple. Does `git pull` perform a fast-forward merge when pulling new changes from origin repository? I read in the documentation that by default it does not, however I do not have any merge commit when pulling.

As an example consider an origin repository with the following history:

```
A -> B -> C -> D
```

And my the working repository is like:

```
A -> B -> C -> W -> X
```

Then, if I pull from remote I get:

```
A -> B -> C -> W -> X -> D
```

without any merge commit between `X` and `D`. There is no merge conflict when pulling new changes. This does not match with what I have understand from the git guide.

Comment: Unless you have changed the same file as the D commit in your example, there is no conflict, so it will just merge your changes with the ones in the remote branch

Comment: It's about `true merge` and `fast-forward merge`. https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

Answer (score 0):

If it behaves like that, you either called `git pull --rebase` or you changed the configuration of your local repository so that `pull` does a rebase by default.

`pull` is a combination of first doing a `fetch` for the branch to be integrated and then by default a `merge` or if config or parameters tell otherwise a `rebase`.

A `merge` will by default do a fast-forward merge if you do not have any commits that only exist in your local branch. You can prevent this via configuration or the parameter `--no-ff` or you can enforce that only fast-forward merges are done via configuration or the paramter `--ff-only` in which case the merge will fail if no fast-forward merge is possible (i. e. you have done local commits).

The behavior you describe cannot be achieved with a `merge`, as it is a `rebase` that changes the history of `D` and thus also its SHA value. It is a complete new commit with you as committer name and now as committer date that introduces the same changes as `D` did and has the same author name and author date. Such a rewritten commit is usually called `D'`.

Comment: But it's not even rebase on pull configuration, b/c after git pull it would be `A -> B -> C -> D -> W -> X` as W and X were local. Perhaps a confusion in writing up the question, no clue.

Comment: Ah, right, you are correct, a rebase would put your commits on top of course. So then without seeing the exact commands you did and the output of `git config -l` it is hard to say how you got to your result. But still a merge should not be able to produce a linear history out of two branches that both had individual commits.

Comment: Not my result, was just commenting on your answer thinking about the OP's outcome in the question. :)